# Bash and variables

Tags: bash

Scenario

$ VAR1=test

$ VAR2=testing

$ VAR3=$VAR1_$VAR2

$ echo $VAR3

testing

I expected "test_testing" as the output. Why its not working? How to output in "test_testing" format? (make $VAR1_$VAR2 work)

Does it interprets VAR3=$VAR1_$VAR2 as VAR3=$(VAR1_$VAR2) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
VAR3="$VAR1"_"$VAR2"
```

it interprets `VAR3=$VAR1_$VAR2` as `$VAR1_ + $VAR2` --- there is no variable named $VAR1_

Comment: An alternative would be: `VAR3=${VAR1}_${VAR2}`

Answer (score 10):

Try

```
$ echo ${VAR1}_${VAR2}
```

Without the braces, it parses the combination as `${VAR1_}${VAR2}`. Since you do not have a `$VAR1_` variable defined, you see only the value of `$VAR2`.

You can see this if you define a variable `$VAR1_`:

```
$ VAR1_=another
$ echo $VAR1_$VAR2
anothertesting
```